# Flutter build appbundle not incrementing version

Tags: flutter, google-play

When I run `flutter build appbundle`, it seems that flutter is not building the app with the correctly specified version in `pubspec.yaml`. In `pubspec.yaml` it says: version: `0.6.3`, but flutter seems to be building the build with version `0.6.2`. That's why I'm getting the error from Play Store every time: [!] Google Api Error: Invalid request - APK specifies a version code that has already been used. When I look at the uploaded versions in the Bundle Explorer, I can't find version `0.6.3`, only `0.6.2`. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The version code of your app is the number after the "+" in your pubspec.yaml

Example :

```
version: "2.0.0+180"
```

This is the version number is 2.0.0 and the version code is 180.